# Get class value from website using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a function that I can run in IE browser. I added this function using `contextmenu` and run it in IE using the right-click menu.

However, the last line is not working as expected.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getSelectionText(w) {
    var text = "";
    if (w.getSelection) {
        text = w.getSelection().toString();
    } 

    return text; 
}
var parentwin = external.menuArguments;
var selection = getSelectionText(parentwin);
alert(selection);
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('publishdate')[0].innerHTML); //I need this to be worked!
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting out of the last line ?

Comment: Can you provide us with a working example of what you have so far? https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am expecting to get the content of the browser.@Exception_al

Comment: Hi, to debug your context menu extensions in IE11. f12>Debug tab, select "Break on all execptions" from the dropdown (looks like a stop sign). Pin the dev tool to the browser, without closing the dev tool return to the browser tab you are on and right-click and select your context menu extension... the dev tool will NOW break on the errors in your extension script... your extension script will be listed and viewable in the debug tab of the dev tool.